# Koszul-complex for bimodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am (which I find a bit embarrassing) quite confused by the following topic.

Let $A$, $B$ be (maybe commutative? let's see) algebras over field $k$ and $E$ be a free $A$-$B$-bimodule; i.e., a free $R = A\otimes B^{op}$-module ($\otimes = \otimes_k$). If there is a map $s\colon E \to R$, I can build the usual Koszul complex $\cdots \to \bigwedge^1 E \to \bigwedge^0 E = R$, with $e_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_d \mapsto \sum \pm s(e_i) e_1 \wedge\dotsb\wedge \hat{e}_i \wedge \dotsb \wedge e_d$.

I think my confusion starts when I start to unwrap that concretely.

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space and $A=B=S(V^*)$. Then $E = A\otimes_k V \otimes_k A^{op}$ is free of rank $\dim V$, and, if I am a bit pedantic in which category the wedge products are taken, $\bigwedge_A^n E \cong A \otimes_k \bigwedge_k^n V \otimes_k A^{op}$ (I hope so; I did not check it fully). The above Koszul complex then would become

$$
\cdots \to A \otimes \bigwedge^1 V \otimes A^{op} \to A\otimes A^{op} 
$$

**Question.** What's the map $s\colon E = A \otimes V \otimes A^{op} \to A \otimes A^{op}$ in this perspective?

For one sided modules, I could take $s\colon A\otimes V \to A, a\otimes v \mapsto a(v)$.
If looking at bimodules should it be $a \otimes v \otimes b \mapsto a(v) 1\otimes b + b(v) a \otimes 1$? Or just $a \otimes v \otimes b \mapsto a(v)b(v)$? I'm inclined to assume the latter is the correct choice (because I think the former would require a somehow strange pairing $A \otimes V \to k$, but, as you probably guess, I am quite confused.

Maybe all my confusion comes from the following irritation: If $A$ (like above) is commutative, any $A$-module is an $A$-$A$-bimodule. However, which was not clear to me, being free as $A$-module (and also being an $A$-$A$-bimodule) is not the same as being free as $A$-$A$-bimodule.

**Question.** Am I right in the last point?